# scripting a Grails app

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to write a script for a Grails application that modifies persistent data, send e-mails to users, etc.

While there's nothing Grails-specific about this - I could accomplish these tasks using JDBC, JavaMail - I'm hoping there's a better way. Specifically, if I could write a Groovy script which has access to the Spring beans, and domain classes defined within the Grails application, it seems like I could save myself a lot of time.

Any suggestions?

- Don

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I'm assuming this a one time script you need to run, rather than some functionality that belongs in the grails app.  For this, you could write a groovy script and run it in the grails console:

```
grails prod console
```

In the console you would have access to the Domain classes (and GORM).  You could then dump the mail/activation/commons-email jars in the lib directory or install the grails [Mail plugin](http://www.grails.org/Mail+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create a gant script. For example a HelloWorld.groovy script can be created with:

```
grails create-script hello-world
```

Within this script you have access to the spring context via the `appCtx` variable and the GrailsApplication instance via the `grailsApp` variable. You can use the latter to load the User domain classes with

```
def artistClass = grailsApp.classLoader.loadClass("com.example.User")
```

and you can then invoke GORM methods in the usual way:

```
artistClass.list()
```